# How can I pass information with a WebClient request to identify the object that gets loaded?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, webclient

I have a collection of custom objects called **DataItems** which contain URIs of **images** that I want to load and put in a collection for my **Silverlight** application to use.

As I process each DataItem, I get its **SourceUri** (e.g. "http://..../picture001.png") and start it **loading**:

```
void LoadNext()
{
    WebClient webClientImgDownloader = new WebClient();
    if (loadedItemIndex < RegisteredDataEntries.Count())
    {
        DataItem dataItem = RegisteredDataEntries[registeredIdCodes[loadedItemIndex]];
        if (dataItem.Kind == DataItemKind.Image)
        {
            webClientImgDownloader.OpenReadCompleted += 
                new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClientImgDownloader_OpenReadCompleted);
            webClientImgDownloader.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(dataItem.SourceUri, 
                UriKind.Absolute));
            webClientImgDownloader.AddObject(dataItem); //????????????????????
            webClientImgDownloader.Headers["idCode"] = dataItem.IdCode; //?????????????
            webClientImgDownloader.ResponseHeaders["idCode"] = dataItem.IdCode; //?????????????
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OnLoadingComplete(this, null);
    }
}
```

Then when the loading of that image has **completed**, I save the image in a **collection**:

```
void webClientImgDownloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dataItemIdCode = e.DataItem.IdCode; //???????????????????
    dataitemIdCode = ((DataItem)sender).IdCode; //?????????????????????

    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(e.Result);

    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = bitmap;
    Images.Add(dataItemIdCode, image);
}
```

**But how do I pass the IdCode of the current DataItem through to my OpenReadCompleted method so that when that image has completed loading, I can also IDENTIFY it according to its IdCode?**

## ANSWER:

Franci's suggestion works, here are the lines for anyone else looking for this::

```
webClientImgDownloader.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(dataItem.SourceUri, 
    UriKind.Absolute), dataItem);
...
DataItem dataItem = e.UserState as DataItem;
```

Answer (score 6):

There's an [`OpenDataAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144212(VS.80).aspx) overload that takes a user token object. You should get this object in the `OpenReadCompletedEventArgs`, in the [`UserState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.userstate(VS.80).aspx) property (inherited from `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`).